# Leer archivo txt y agregarlo a dos arreglos en java

Tags: java, array

Me piden un método donde tengo que cargar un archivo txt y agregarlo a dos arreglos, uno de texto y otro double.
Tengo el siguiente código y quiero saber como agregarlo a los métodos, ya tengo una idea pero no se si este bien.

Nota los dos arreglos ncelular y rminutos ya fueron declarados.

**El código no lo he probado porque me faltan 5 métodos mas

```
public RegistroLlamadas() {

    String linea;
    String[] partes;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader("Archivos\\Registro.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            partes = linea.split("@");

        }

        ncelular[0] = linea;
        rminutos[0] = Double.parseDouble(linea);

        fr.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo por el código que el fichero de texto está compuesto por varias líneas, y que una "@" separa el número y los minutos.

En ese caso, dentro del mismo bucle "while" deberías ir almacenando los resultados en los arreglos o arrays.

No sé muy bien en qué consiste el problema, pero si no sabes de antemano el número de filas que tiene tu fichero, no vas a poder crear un array con el tamaño adecuado. Yo usaría una colección, ya que su tamaño es dinámico.

Por ejemplo:

```
public RegistroLlamadas() {

    String linea;
    String[] partes;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader("Archivos\\Registro.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int posicion = 0;
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            partes = linea.split("@");

            ncelular[posicion] = linea;
            rminutos[posicion] = Double.parseDouble(linea);

            posicion++;

        }


        fr.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Un posible problema con el que te podrías encontrar es que no puedas saber de antemano cuántas líneas tiene el fichero, y por tanto, no vas a poder crear un array que tenga el tamaño adecuado. Una posible solución a esto es que en vez de un array "primitivo" utilices una colección dinámica, como ArrayList.